# What is the solution to level 89?

Tags: ios, hundreds

In *Hundreds*, level Eighty Nine has five time-shrinking dots, but they're so close together that it seems impossible to get to 100 without a collision:

[image]

I've tried many combinations of neighbours, but there simply doesn't seem to be enough clearance for any combination of them to expand enough to total 100. How can this level be completed (without unlocking and using the secret power, which makes it trivial)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just completed this level, but it took me awhile and it is not easy.  You basically have to increase each bubble to its maximum size without touching the adjacent bubble.  You can figure out how big each can get by pressing two adjacent bubbles at a time.  Clockwise from the top left its roughly 28, 17, 17, 16, 22 (which is exactly 100, so no room for error). To get 100, I increased each bubble close to its maximum size and then kept tapping each quickly and  franctically until after about 15 tries I hit the magic combo.  Again, not easy but keep trying and eventually you'll get it.  Good luck.